# Using Custom Extension Methods inside LinQ (Compare two strings)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I wanna create a comparer for LinQ that is simplified. this is my current code.

```
DBContext.product_type
                    .Where(x => x.name.ToLower()(filter.ToLower()) 
                        || x.description..ToLower()(filter.ToLower()) 
                        || x.online_category.description..ToLower()(filter.ToLower()))
```

I wanna simplify it using linQ extension method. So far this is what I got.

```
DBContext.product_type
                    .Where(x => x.name.CompareToLower(filter) 
                        || x.description.CompareToLower(filter) 
                        || x.online_category.description.CompareToLower(filter))
```

```
public static bool CompareToLower(this string str, string comparer)
{
    if (str.ToLower().Contains(comparer.ToLower()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the error im getting

> linq to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean CompareToLower(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: As the error message says `CompareToLower` can not be converted to SQL query. C# LINQ queries in EF is eventually translated to SQL Query and run against the database to retrieve the data. You should store `filter.ToLower()` to some variable and use `ToLower()` and `Contains` method on column names directly in LINQ instead of creating extension method. `.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Contains(lowerFilter)`

Comment: not a bad idea. Thank you for this.

Comment: Does you sql setup for case sensitive collation? By default SQL does case insensitvite search. In that case you don't need `ToLower` at all.

Comment: yes I set it up with case sensitive collation

Comment: @whizzle that's a bad idea. Change it to case-*in*sensitive. You obviously want case-*in*sensitive comparisons, so it doesn't make sense to use a case-sensitive collation. Your query won't be able to use any indexes if you have to convert to lowercase each time, forcing a full table scan. That's going to be extremely expensive for anything but the smallest tables

Comment: @whizzle as for `x.name.CompareToLower(filter) `, that's already available through [String.Equals(string,StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_).  EF may even understand this and try to perform a case-insensitive comparison BUT it would still have to scan the entire table

Comment: Have you considered to use `EF.Functions.Like`? Please bear in mind that the [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like) can be case sensitive or insensitive.

Comment: How is this legal: `x.name.ToLower()(filter.ToLower()) `?

Comment: Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) you can create methods that are expanded before translation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep i will change to case-insensitive collation.but first i will also try String.Equals and EF.Functions.Like. Thank you

Comment: @whizzle that's not a good idea. The query won't be able to use any indexes covering `description` and will end up checking *every* row in the table. That's what a table scan is. It's not just the slowest way possible, it also locks the entire table, preventing other connections from making *any* modifications until the query ends. That's how deadlocks happen

Comment: @whizzle besides, `Equals` is *very* different from `Like`. If you use `Like` without wildcards, it's just an `Equals`. If you use `abc%`, it's essentially a range search that can be accelerated by indexes. `%def` or `%bc%` though, can't use indexes. If you have such queries you should probably use [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) queries

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods like that cannot be converted to SQL Query.

The answer provided by @meysamasadi will work, but will fetch your entire table and do the comparison on client side.

If you want the comparison to occur on the database-side, the most efficient way would be to change your collation to case-insensitive (as suggested in the comments).

As an alternative you can use following code:

```
DBContext.product_type
    .Where(x => 
        EF.Functions.Like(x.Name, filter) 
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.Description, filter) 
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.online_category.description, filter))
```

** Note that using the above method you can also include wildcards in the filter and patterns
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-5.0